# Python finding many elements in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below

```
df = 
     A      B 
0   foo    10
1   goo    20
2   hoo    30
3   foo    40
4   goo    50
3   hoo    60
4   goo    70
```

I want to find if ['foo','hoo'] exists in df['A'] and I want to create a new dataframe using those rows.

```
My code: 
idx = []
for i in ['foo','hoo']:
    idx.append(df[df['A']==i].index)
newdf = df.index[idx]
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: `df[df.A.isin(['foo','hoo'])]`..?

Comment: `isin` operator. `df[df['A'].isin(['foo', 'hoo'])]`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html

Comment: @yatu I'm not sure but they may want if *both* are present... so maybe: `{'foo', 'hoo'}.issubset(df['A'])`...

Comment: Doesn't seem so following the logic of the code above @jon (not sure eithr)

Comment: @Mainland What would be the desired output for your example?

Answer (score 0):

This might work ? -

```
new_df = df[(df['A'] == 'foo') | (df['A'] == 'hoo')].reset_index(drop=True)
```